# How can I make state updating asynchronous in React+Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm writing an incremental-style game in React and I have this setInterval inside `App.ts:`

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const loop = setInterval(() => {
      if (runStatus) {
        setTime(time + 1);
      }
    }, rate);

    return () => clearInterval(loop);
  });
```

I've also got various event handlers along the lines of:

```html
<button onClick={() => increment(counter + 1)}>Increment</button>
```

Unfortunately, if I click that button multiple times in a second, it will block the setInterval from updating the `time` state.

This state using the hooks as well as Redux stored state.

How can I, at the very least, make my setInterval tick reliably, so that I can click around the page without blocking it?

Comment: try putting `[]` as your dependency for `useEffect`.  Otherwise every time your state changes, your generating a new interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like that

`[]` empty dependency means only execute when a component will mount.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const loop = setInterval(() => {
      if (runStatus) {
        setTime(prev => prev + 1);
      }
    }, rate);

    return () => clearInterval(loop);
}, []); <--- add that []
```

**Notes**

1. adding time as a dependency will create an infinite loop
2. you need to add `runStatus` or `rate` variable as a dependency if its dynamic state

Comment: This runs on every re-render. Is this desired?

Comment: Your IIFE and `async` are not doing anything useful here, just the `[]` is all you need..

Comment: `setTime((time) => time + 1);` would work. As you have added empty deps, `time` will not get updated.

Comment: sorry I forgot that but putting time dependency creates an infinite loop?

Comment: Don't put a time dependency. Keep it as above. Instead, pass a function as argument to setTime. That way, setTime will always pick the latest value of time. Functions can be passed to setState.

Comment: @Keith got it, I will remove it

Comment: No probs, and yes put @NishargShah `setTime` callback version in too, as the useEffect is going to be scoped to the original `time` otherwise..

Comment: Fantastic, that did it for me. Thanks a bunch @Nishargshah + the rest :)

Comment: What if `runStatus` or `rate` change? Presumably they can otherwise they would be hard coded. They should be included in the dependency array.

Comment: @lawrence-witt Indeed, If `runStatus` and `rate` are props that are sideEffects, put them in the dependancy,..  eg.  `[runStatus, rate]`.  If there globals then not required.